# Zimbra, how to turn off spamassasin and clamAV

Tags: spamassassin, zimbra, clamav

We are using Zimbra 5.0.18 and I like to know how permanetly disable spamassasin and clamav.

We have ironport so no wories about spam and malware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're on 6.0 so I'm not certain it's the same, but we can set this in the administration console.  From the admin console, Choose Servers, highlight your server, and click the services tab.  Uncheck Anti-spam and Anti-virus and save.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to set the *spam lover* Amavis' option:

```
zmprov md domain.com +amavisSpamLover TRUE
```

This can be set per domain or per single user.

*Note: this works from Zimbra 7.x onwards*